# Incompatibility regarding color parameters in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, colors, rgb

I **must** use **RAW 8** color Mode for my project, according to some research it's having **8 pixels per bit**, and it has got **3 channels** since it's a color image that I want to display. The project was OK when It's about to display a **24 Bpp** using the **sRGB** but this is not needed.

I want to show one captured image via OpenCV using as a start:

```
IplImage* img =cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

And when I want to save it:

```
cvSaveImage("C:/1.png", img);
```

More updates: The image that I'm having is 1/3 of the total size now and the 2/3 other part is black. It works good when I'm displaying in 1 channel, using 8 Bpp. But I would like to deal with 3 channels though.

Any solution?

Comment: you are not capturing any image, but just creating an empty image object

Comment: Capturing is a part of the code which works correctly.
The main problem is just the compatibility between IPL DEPTH and BPP used. I have already said that when it's about to display a 24 BPP, it goes well.

Comment: Can someone lookup that?

Comment: No would know anything?